# slam example totally follow the navigation tutorials

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation, rviz, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is ros doc tutorials able to provide a basic full online slam example totally follow the navigation tutorials?
Why I want to ask this because I couldn't find any slam package which totally follow the navigation tutorials and with laser range finder.I feel not easy to get information around everywhere on ros docs.

What I need are:

1.totally follow navigation tutorials

it means the package has these packages : tf,odmo,base,laser...(not combined together)

2.laser range finder(hokuyo node)

3.simple robot cad model on gazebo

4.rviz to show real laser data

5.using rviz to show the map and set goal

6.dynamic gmapping (not using static map)

If it is possible,thank you very much!!
gratitude~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10475/slam-example-totally-follow-the-navigation-tutorials/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [pr2_simulator](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator) has all those things and there are tutorials for building a map in gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-06**:
Thank you~maybe I miss something,I will try to figure out~

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-05**:
It does simulate the whole pr2 including hokuyo, tf, odom, etc. I've given the link in my post, you can follow the tutorials there.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-05**:
Dose pr2_simulator have hokuyo node,rviz,and codes on navigation tutorials? Where is the code or link of pr2_simulator with tf,odmo,base,laser packages? thank you~